# How to set cookies to a WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a WebView that loads a certain URL site , I am able to add User Agent String using the following code. I need to set some cookies for the site to enable a mobile view format. Something like the picture below. I want to set the cookies before loading the site, so that on loading it shows up the way I want.

```
browser.getSettings().setUserAgentString("User Agent stuff");
```

[image]

The examples I found by searching are not straight forward and I couldn't figure it out. I hope I can get some assistance here, I will appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`CookieManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) API. Be sure that your input data into the [`setCookie()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setCookie%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function is in the corresponding format in comparison to those cookies appearing in real web browsers/Wireshark etc.

Comment: CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
   cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
   cookieManager.setCookie("website", "cookie"); This code did it. Thanks for directing me.